# Rules to follow in the development stage, so it makes the deployment stage easier

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

What's your advice/points for developers to follow or avoid in the development and early stages of developing a database driven asp.net websites. so we could have an easy and efficient deployment -specially in development(creating) the database to be easily deployed in the feature on my shared hosting server- .

**Edit 1**

I'm sorry, but still I didn't get any detailed advice specially about the database.
I mean, I'm creating my website database using the SqlExpress -am not sure which version. this is from the connection string "AttachDbFilename="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DB.mdf"- . I use the Database Diagrams option in the studio to create FKs and create the relations between table.

So how can I copy this database structure and data in the future to be used on a server. I was thinking maybe I should do it all in SQL and save the script and run it later on a database that I'd create on the deployment server.

Just some thoughts! I hope I'd find some great ways to do it from developers who already deployed websites before!

Comment: SQL Server or MS Access or MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible you should practice an iterative development approach including continuous deployment. Even if you deploy iteratively to a staging area you will be exercising many of your processes. This gives you a chance to fail early and often, there by making your final deployment smoother.

Answer (score 1):

From a prioritisation perspective: software development has the end goal delivered functionality, and if you can't deploy, then you can't deliver *any* functionality.

For most projects - web or otherwise - the first story should be something like "As a user, I want to be able to install the product, so I can run it."  This usually causes the development of the deployment mechanism to be done very early, and maintained as the codebase changes when additional stories are completed.

The deployment mechanism should be your way of delivering functionality to the customer for approval and testing.

It is very important to avoid getting to the end of a project and having to ask "okay, now how do we deploy it?"

*Edited to add:* Also make 100% certain you're aware of the licencing and distribution restrictions on any third-party components you're using.  Pay particular attention to any Free code that may be covered by licences like the GPL.  Check whether any commercial components you're using require royalties per deployment, or require special 'server' licences.